# Ext JS Charts shows Y-axis label in wrong / reverse order

Tags: extjs

Below is the code corresponding to the screenshot that I added. If you refer to the data fields at the beginning of the code, you will see that the Labels on the Y-axis shows wrong.

and importing these libs, which is the same import in the sample chars that I found in this official chart preview [link](http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-4-preview-drawing-and-charting/) (the zip file is at the end of the article, and the bar chart in it is also wrong!!!):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../resources/css/ext.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../ext-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../ext-chart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Bar3.js"></script>
```

Then I imported the following libs (the same libs that they import in [this sample](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/charts/Bar.html)):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext-all.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext-all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Bar3.js"></script>
```

I got the correct result.

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
var chart;

var store1 = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
fields:['name', 'data1'],
data: [
    {name:'Jan', data1: 2000},{name:'Feb', data1: 1800},
    {name:'Mar', data1: 1500},{name:'Apr', data1: 1000}
]});


chart = new Ext.chart.Chart({
    renderTo: Ext.get('graphDiv'),
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    animate: true,
    shadow: true,
    store: store1,
    autoScroll: true,
    axes: [{
        type: 'Numeric',
        position: 'bottom',
        fields: ['data1'],
        label: {
           renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0,0')
        },
        title: 'Number of Hits'
    }, {
        type: 'Category',
        position: 'left',
        fields: ['name'],
        reverse: true,
        title: 'Month of the Year'
    }],
    series: [{
        type: 'bar',
        axis: 'bottom',
        highlight: true,
        label: {
            display: 'insideEnd',
            field: 'data1',
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0'),
            orientation: 'horizontal',
            color: '#333',
           'text-anchor': 'middle',
           contrast: true
        },
        xField: 'name',
        yField: 'data1'
    }]
});
});
```

[image: Ext JS Bar Chart]

Answer (score 2):

**A known bug of extjs 4.0.0! Just an upgrade to 4.1.x will solve the problem.**